# Setting the color of action bar and text when app is shown in list of backgrounded apps

Tags: android

On a Lollipop device, when I background an app and then pull up the list of apps that are backgrounded, I see something like this:

[image: Android 5.0 list of backgrounded apps]

How does one modify the color of the action bar displayed there and the color of the text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use setTaskDescription() method from your activity:

```
setTaskDescription(new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(label, icon, color));
```

More informations: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTaskDescription(android.app.ActivityManager.TaskDescription)

By default Android will take the activity's icon, activity's label and the color from android:colorPrimary attribute of your theme.

Comment: So this is how Chrome does it!

Comment: @EugenPechanec With Chrome you can even colorized the tab based on your website. Just add  <meta name="theme-color" content="#your_color"> in the header of your html page.

Comment: Perfect! Disappointed Android does not let you specify the text color yourself. :/

Comment: Be aware that this won't work if you do it in `onCreate()`. `onResume()` is fine, though.